# java return mixed

Tags: java

Да не побьют меня адепты явы, каюсь, постоянно сказываюсь на PHP.
Есть функция, которая парсит строчку в файле.

Типа того:

NAME: blabla1| NUMBER: 2221| SURNAME: balbal999

Хотелось бы name, surname отдавать строкой, а number - числом.
Правильно я понимаю, что единственный нормальный выход -

```
int number = 0;
try{
  number = Integer.parseInt(my_super_parsing_function("NUMBER",input_string));
}
 catch(NumberFormatException e){
  //пишем грозное сообщение о сбое в структуре файла
}
```

Или есть способ перегрузить ее двумя разными выводами с ОДИНАКОВЫМИ параметрами, просто в зависимости от одного из них?

Comment: Сигнатура метода в Java содержит и параметры и возвращаемое значение, так что перегрузить не получится. Надо возвращать структуру/класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего возвращать структуру:

```
class Parameter
{
    public String Name;
    public int Number;
    public String Surname;
}

Parameter parseLine(string line)
{
    Parameter p = new Parameter();
    String[] parts = line.split("|");
    if (parts.Length != 3)
        throw SomeSternFormatException();
    p.Name = GetValue(parts[0], "NAME");
    p.Number = Integer.parseInt(GetValue(parts[1], "NUMBER"));
    p.Surname = GetValue(parts[2], "SURNAME");
    return p;
}

String getValue(String input, String expectedKey)
{
    String[] parts = input.split(":");
    if (parts.Length != 2)
        throw SomeSternFormatException();
    String key = parts[0].Trim();
    if (!expectedKey.equals(key))
        throw SomeSternFormatException();
    return parts[1].Trim();
}
```

(Этот код исходит из строго определённого порядка и количества частей.)

---

Для случая произвольного порядка я бы сделал как-то так:

```
Parameter parseLine(string line)
{
    Parameter p = new Parameter();
    String[] parts = line.split("|");
    HashMap<String, String> argmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    foreach (String part : parts)
    {
        String[] keyvalue = getKeyValue(part);
        String key = keyvalue[0];
        if (argmap.containsKey(key))
            throw SomeSternFormatException();
        argmap.put(key, value);
    }

    if (argmap.size() != 3)
        throw SomeSternFormatException();
    p.Name = argmap["NAME"];
    p.Number = Integer.parseInt(argmap["NUMBER"]);
    p.Surname = argmap["SURNAME"];
    return p;
}

String[] getKeyValue(String input)
{
    String[] parts = input.split(":");
    if (parts.Length != 2)
        throw SomeSternFormatException();
    parts[0] = parts[0].Trim();
    parts[1] = parts[1].Trim();
    return parts;
}
```

---

Исключения пусть, кстати, ловит вызывающая сторона.

Comment: @VladD, дык эту структуру-то я и пытаюсь получить.
Значит мне надо понять как использовать enum для запихивания string в Switch, что нужно, чтобы знать какое из полей заполнить.

Comment: @knes: дополнил ответ.

Comment: @knes: или у вас поля могут идти в произвольном порядке?

Comment: Могут идти, а могут и не идти. В смысле, это зависит только от меня. В моем решении через indexOf и substring совместно с expectedKey.length() оно вытаскивало просто из любого места. Так что это не проблема, дальше разберусь. Спасибо.

Comment: @knes: пожалуйста! Добавил вариант с произвольным порядком.

Answer (score 2):

есть пара хороших вариантов.

- Вы же знаете, какой тип будет на выходе? ну так и запрашивайте нужный. Да, нужно будет две функции - `GetAsString` и `GetAsInt`.
- Возвращайте объект, который имеет различные поля, которые идентифицируют тип результата.

Comment: Первый вариант либо плодит повторы кода(парсинг-то идет одинаково), либо реализует приведенный мной пример внутри GetAsInt...

Второй вариант не очень понятно как сделать.

    public class retclass{
      public boolean is_int;
      public int result_int;
      public String result_string;  
    }

какой-то он несуразный. Или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Если у Вас возникает необходимость в повторах, значит у Вас проблемы. Делайте один метод, который возвращает в виде строки, а метод, который возвращает целое, просто вызывает первый метод и преобразовывает в число.

В противном случае этот повтор появиться в каждом месте вызова первого метода.

второй вариант хорошо реализуется на плюсах

     enum result_type {
       R_INT, R_STRING, R_URL
     }; 
     struct Result {
        result_type type;
        void * data;
     };

На Java можно сделать, если применить наследование. Один абстрактный класс и на каждый вариант ответа наследник.

Comment: Если у Вас возникает необходимость в повторах, значит у Вас проблемы// Именно. Поэтому и уточняю.

Comment: @KoVadim http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2694

Comment: Вот понаписывают таких костылей, как @alexlz предлагает, а потом жалуются, что же оно десятки гигов выедает. Не нужно в один язык тащить конструкции с другого.

Comment: хорошо реализуется на плюсах// Это кто?
У меня он сослался на неизвестный symbol struct.

Comment: плюсы - это С++. Но java программисты этот юмор не понимают:)

Comment: Тем более PHP... Патамучта J# существует, вроде как. Вот у меня и зародилось подозрение, что есть че-то типа J++. 
Логично же такое предположить, если вопрос по яве? =))

Comment: Если читать внимательно мой комментарий, то видно, что я противоставляю. Мне с++ ближе, чем java, хотя на ней я много писал.

J++ если и будет существовать, то только в страшных снах. Хотя по факту, современные java компиляторы + jvm делают нативный код (не для всего кода, только для горячих кусков).